# Por que está retornando "Posição Invalida"?

Tags: c, if, else, void

Quando digito 3, ao invés de pedir a Posição que quero inserir, retorna 'Opção Invalida'. Alguém saberia me dizer porque? Segue o código:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int Lista[5];
void Esvaziar()
{
    for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
    {
        Lista[x]=0;
    }
    printf("Lista esvaziada com sucesso!\n");
    _sleep(2000);
}
void Imprimir()
{
    for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
    {
        printf("[%d]",Lista[x]);
    }
    _sleep(2000);
}
int ListaVazia()
{
    if(Lista[0]==0)
    {
        return 0;//se ele retornar 0, a lista esta vazia
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;//se ele retornar 1, a lista não esta vazia
    }
}
int ListaCheia()
{
    if(Lista[4]!=0)
    {
        return 1;//se ele retornar 1, a lista esta cheia
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;// se ele retornar 0, a lista não esta cheia
    }
}
void Insere()
{
    int pos=0,valor;
    if(Lista[0]!=0)
    {
        printf("\nPosicao: ");
        scanf("%d",&pos);
    }   
    if(pos>=0 && pos<=4 && Lista[pos-1]!=0)
    {
        printf("\nValor: ");
        scanf("%d",&valor); 
        if(Lista[0]==0)
            Lista[0]=valor;
        else if(Lista[pos]!=0)
        {
            for(int x=4;x>pos;x--)
            {
                Lista[x]=Lista[x-1];    
            }       
            Lista[pos]=valor;
        }
        else if(Lista[pos-1]!=0 && Lista[pos]==0)
        {
            Lista[pos]=valor;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Posicao invalida\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}
void Retirar()
{
    int valor;
    printf("Valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&valor);
    if(valor==0)
    {
        printf("Valor invalido\n");
        _sleep(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
        {
            if(valor==Lista[x])
            {
                if(Lista[x+1]==0)
                {
                    Lista[x]=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    while(x<4)
                    {
                        Lista[x]=Lista[x+1];
                        x++;
                    }
                    Lista[4]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void Alterar()
{
    int pos, valor;
    printf("Posicao: ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    if(Lista[pos]==0)
    {
        printf("Posicao invalida\n");
        _sleep(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&valor);
        if(valor == 0)
        {
            printf("Valor invalido\n");
            _sleep(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            Lista[pos]=valor;
        }
    }
}
int Menu()
{
    int opcao;
    printf("0 - Sair\n");
    printf("1 - Esvaziar\n");
    printf("2 - Imprimir\n");
    printf("3 - Inserir\n");
    printf("4 - Retirar\n");
    printf("5 - Alterar\n");
    printf("OPCAO: ");
    scanf("%d",&opcao);
    return opcao;
}
main()
{
    int op,verifica;
    do{ 
        system("cls");
        op=Menu();
        if(op==1)
        {
            Esvaziar();
        }
        else if(op==2)
        {
            Imprimir();
        }
        else if(op==3)
        {
            verifica=ListaCheia();
            if(verifica==1)
            {
                printf("Lista esta cheia\n");
                _sleep(1000);
            }
            else
                Insere();
        }
        else if(op==4)
        {
            verifica=ListaVazia();
            if(verifica==0)
            {
                printf("Lista vazia\n");
                _sleep(1000);
            }
            else 
                Retirar();
        }
        else if(op==5)
        {
            verifica=ListaVazia();
            if(verifica==0)
            {
                printf("Lista vazia\n");
                _sleep(1000);
            }
            else 
                Alterar();
        }

    }while(op!=0);
}
```

Comment: Esse código jamais exibirá “Opção Invalida”.

Answer (score 0):

As condições que fazem pular as inserções são `Lista[0] != 0` e `Lista[pos-1] != 0`.
Uma solução simples seria, dentro da função `Inserir()`, trocar os operadores `!=` de `if(Lista[0]!=0)` e `if(pos>=0 && pos<=4 && Lista[pos-1]!=0)` por `==`:

```c
void Insere()
{
    int pos=0,valor;
    if(Lista[0]==0) // <- Aqui
    {
        printf("\nPosicao: ");
        scanf("%d",&pos);
    }   
    if(pos>=0 && pos<=4 && (ListaVazia() || Lista[pos-1]!=0)) // <- E aqui
    {
        printf("\nValor: ");
        scanf("%d",&valor); 
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Posicao invalida\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Porém, `Lista[pos-1]` irá retornar valores fora do vetor (lixo de memória) quando `pos` equivaler 0 (ao inserir pela primeira vez, por exemplo). Portanto, verifique antes se `pos` não é 0 ou melhor, se a lista está vazia (`ListaVazia()`), assumindo que `Lista[pos-1] != 0` serve para saber se a posição anteiror em Lista está ocupada.

Também aconselho chamar a função `Esvazia()` antes de ler a opção do menu, para garantir que a lista em si esteja sem lixo de memória ao iniciar o programa.

Comment: Lista[pos-1] para pos=0 pegará lixo de memória, certo?

Comment: Tem razão, editei minha resposta para corrigir isso.